# bind_rows of dplyr R package changes column names, if they are numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

In the following minimal example bind_rows of the dplyr package is changing colnames from numbers to X1, X2, X3. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can prevent this?

```
df1<-data.frame("1"=c(1,2,3),"2"=c(1,2,3))

df2<-data.frame("2"=c(1,2,3),"3"=c(1,2,3))

library(dplyr)

df3<-bind_rows(df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's `data.frame`, not `bind_rows`, that is changing your column names. (Look at `df1` or `df2` to confirm.) We need `check.names = FALSE` in `data.frame` call as by default it is `TRUE`.  According to `?data.frame`

> check.names - logical. If TRUE then the names of the variables in the data frame are checked to ensure that they are syntactically valid variable names and are not duplicated. If necessary they are adjusted (by make.names) so that they are.

```
df1 <- data.frame("1"=c(1,2,3),"2"=c(1,2,3), check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot! Is there an option to set check.names = FALSE on an already existing data frame or to make a query if this is set? Sorry I am new to R.

Comment: @S.Maria If it is already created.  Then you can change the names with `names(df1) <- sub("^X", "", names(df1))`